# Select specific item in XML collection

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Consider the following XML

```
<account>
    <discussionPoints>
        <education category="a" value="1"/>
        <education category="b" value="42"/>
        <education category="c" value="55"/>
    </discussionPoints>
</account>
```

I'm trying to get the value of the value of the education where the category is "a". The particular education may or may not exist. The discussionPoints collection will always exist, though it could be empty. I'm new to XSLT and am needing some direction.

---

**EDIT** Fixed incorrect closing tag

Comment: Use the following XPath expression: `/account/discussionPoints/education[@category='a']/@value`

Comment: That was it! If you wouldn't mind, make that an answer so I may select it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following XPath expression:

`/account/discussionPoints/education[@category='a']/@value`

It follows the child axis three times to match an `education` element. Then it checks the attribute axis for `category` without following it (as stated in the predicate) and then, provided that the value of `category` is `'a'`, it follows the attribute axis again to fetch the value of `value` attribute.